# print ready pdf in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to know the process of making a print ready pdf in adobe photoshop. Like in illustrator we need to outline the fonts, CMYK color etc.

what I have to do to create a print ready pdf in photoshop.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your print shop asking for? Is this litho, inkjet…?

Comment: Technically one need not outline fonts in Illustrator if you send a PDFx file for reproduction. So If you're sending raw AI files.. that's, well, out of the norm.

Comment: @Scott, it doesn't even have to be a PDFx file. It can have *Standard* set to *None* and still have fonts embedded.

Comment: Possibly @Wolff .. everything which leaves my desk for reproduction is PDFx though. I do *know* there are shops out there that actually request AI files. I just don't ever have any contact with those shops.

Comment: @Scott most PDF files we receive and files I make myself don't have a standard defined. Makes no difference for the printed result really. Just easier to check/preflight and Acrobat automatically picks the right *Simulation Profile* so you don't have to guess. The CMYK values are the same and our RIP doesn't care. But I'm digressing here.

Comment: The world is much more predicable when work never leaves your office @Wolff `:)`